# Why does my training loop completely skip after the first epoch in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am currently trying to train a neural network in PyTorch. I first initialize:

```py
#Start training
import torch.optim as optim
import itertools
model = unet()
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=1e-4)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
criterion = criterion.to(device)
```

And I define a training and validation function:

```py
#TRAINING

def train(model, iterator,optimizer,criterion):
  running_loss = 0.0
  epoch_acc = 0.0
  model.train()
  for (batch_idx,batch) in enumerate(iterator):
    
    spad,ground_truth = batch
    spad = spad.cuda()
    ground_truth = ground_truth.cuda()
    output = model(spad)

      #Compare reconstructed depth from SPAD to ground truth.
    loss = criterion(output,ground_truth)
    acc = ssim_accuracy(output,ground_truth)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()
    epoch_acc += acc.item()
    if(batch_idx % 10 == 9):
      print(epoch_acc / len(iterator))
      print(len(iterator))

  return running_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

```py
def evaluate(model,iterator,criterion):
  epoch_loss = 0.0
  epoch_acc = 0.0

  with torch.no_grad():
    for (batch_idx,batch) in enumerate(iterator):
      spad,ground_truth = batch
      spad = spad.cuda()
      ground_truth = ground_truth.cuda()

      predictions = model(spad)
      #predictions = predictions.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)


      acc = ssim_accuracy(predictions, ground_truth)
      loss = criterion(predictions,ground_truth)
            
      #keep track of loss and accuracy
      epoch_loss += loss.item()
      epoch_acc += acc.item()

    #return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

Finally, I train:

```py
EPOCHS = 10
print(len(train_iterator))
for epoch in range(1,EPOCHS+1):
  print("EPOCH " + str(epoch))
  train_loss,train_acc = train(model,train_iterator,optimizer,criterion)
  valid_loss,valid_acc = evaluate(model,test_iterator,criterion)
    
    # Showing statistics
  print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
  print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
```

However, after the first epoch, the program completely stops and gives me "Train Loss = 0.00 | Train Acc = 0.00" for every epoch after, see below. Python does not even run the training loop and I have no idea why.

This is the output for a sample training, I make it return the current training accuracy after every 10 loops (that's the 0.04549... numbers). As you can see, it is certainly improving in accuracy. However, it completely skips any epochs after the first epoch.

```
88
EPOCH 1
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py:226: MatReadWarning: Duplicate variable name "None" in stream - replacing previous with new
Consider mio5.varmats_from_mat to split file into single variable files
  matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
0.045496476983482186
88
0.09700817919590256
88
0.15018199756741524
88
0.21078435704112053
88
0.2749210965226997
88
0.33811280131340027
88
    Train Loss: 1.706 | Train Acc: 37.47%
     Val. Loss: 2.058 |  Val. Acc: 54.50%
EPOCH 2
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 3
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 4
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 5
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 6
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 7
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 8
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 9
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
EPOCH 10
    Train Loss: 0.000 | Train Acc: 0.00%
     Val. Loss: 0.000 |  Val. Acc: 0.00%
```

If I make the training dataset set smaller or make it iterate over less of it, then the accuracy goes down. However, I have tried things like making it loop through half the data in one training loop, then make it train through the other half, and it still stops after the first loop and ignores the second loop. Do you know what might be the issue?

Could this be a problem with Google Colab? I doubt it, but I am using the free GPU that it provides right now. Maybe something to do with running out of memory? I have had it run out of memory before, but the system itself tells me if this is the case, rather than just refuse to run anything after a certain point with no explanation.

Comment: How did you define `train_iterator` and `test_iterator`? It looks as if they could only be iterated over once, similar to a generator. But you can't ask the length of a generator so `len(train_iterator)` shouldn't have worked. So my guess it's your data source that is a generator.

Comment: Thank you for the question. StackOverflow won't let me edit my post to include the code, but here it is: https://pastebin.com/5nDSRMKt

Comment: Try passing `train_dataloader` and `test_dataloader` directly to `train` and `evaluate` respectively. That is, don't call `iter` on them.